# l was learning about multiprocessing in Python and I came across a variable that is 'list' and also 'object', how is this possible?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

**That a code what l was testing:**

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import funcoes

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = mp.Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = mp.Array('i', range(10))

    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=[num, arr])
    p.start()

    print(arr[:])
    print(num.value)

    time.sleep(1)

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])

    print(type(arr[:]))

    print(arr)
    print(type(arr))
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
0.0

3.1415927
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]

<class 'list'>

<SynchronizedArray wrapper for <multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_long_Array_10 object at 0x000001A0857DD040>>
<class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.SynchronizedArray'>
```

How come the *`object`* has the same name as the *`list`*?

just by putting `[:]` at the end of *`arr`*.

---

**So l did some tests:**

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

class arr:
    def test():
        print('anything')

print(type(arr.test))
print(type(arr))

print(type(arr()))
print(type(arr[:]))
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'function'>

<class 'type'>

<class '__main__.arr'>

#Error: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

---

**and another test:**

```
class arr:
    def test():
        print('anything')

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

print(type(arr))
print(type(arr[:]))

print(type(arr()))
print(type(arr.test))
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'list'>

<class 'list'>

#Error: 'list' object is not callable

#Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'test'
```

Someone can explain that to me?

Comment: You're asking why a slice of an `multiprocessing.Array` returns a `list` even though the original object is is a different type? I imagine there's either a good reason or it's just an implementation detail

Comment: Yes l think, why `arr` is different from `arr[:]` .

Comment: `arr[:]` is taking a slice of the `multiprocessing.Array` and when you slice a `mp.Array` you get a plain list back. They are different types

Comment: but for example `list= [1,2,3,4]` , `list` equal `list[:]` , and type of `list` and `list[:]` are `<class 'list'>`. They are same type same value

Comment: True, but that just means that the built-in list type returns an instance of itself when sliced. Different types will behave in different ways. `[:]` is not shorthand for making a copy of something, it just so happens that lists have this behaviour

Comment: exactly, you can take slice of any sequential data type and it returns a list (the slice of original data). Just that in this case the slice is the whole array(`mp.Array`). So `arr[:]` refers to a copy of the orignal array and not the original array itself, and as the slices are stored and returned as lists, so it shows list as its type. Basically `arr` and `arr[:]` are not the same variable, both are referring to different data and even have different types in this case. Note that if you took a slice of a list it will still return a list.

Comment: @K450 well said. It's worth mentioning that a type can chose to return whatever it likes when sliced

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes and thank you for mentioning that. I wasn't able to edit that in time

Comment: l think  l got it, thank u guys :)